# Why the print function doesn't work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Why don't the print methods work in the function total?

```
def main():
    firstAge = int(input('Enter your age:'))
    secondAge = int(input("Enter your best friend's age:"))

def total(firstAge,secondAge):
    response = sums(firstAge,secondAge)
    print(response)  

def sums(num1, num2):
    result = int(num1 + num2)
    return result

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not calling total function inside main function

change your main function to add total function inside like this

```
def main():
    firstAge = int(input('Enter your age:'))
    secondAge = int(input("Enter your best friend's age:"))
    total(firstAge,secondAge)
```